# How to convert datestrings in an array generated by $push in aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783350/how-to-convert-dates-in-an-array-with-datefromstring) question,

I'm trying to convert timestamps in an array generated from `$push` in aggregation pipeline to convert dates with `$dateFromString`

Aggreagtion Pipeline:

```
  {
    '$match': {
      'metadata.client': 'client_id'
    }
  }, {
    '$limit': 10
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'steps', 
      'localField': 'connection_id', 
      'foreignField': 'connection_id', 
      'as': 'joined_steps_array'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id', 
      'tsArr': {
        '$push': '$joined_steps_array.timestamp'
      }, 
      'stepsArr': {
        '$push': '$joined_steps_array.metadata.step_info'
      }, 
      'metadata': {
        '$push': {
          '$arrayElemAt': [
            '$joined_steps_array', 0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 1, 
      'convertedTsArr': {
        '$map': {
          'input': '$tsArr', 
          'in': {
            '$dateFromString': {
              'dateString': '$$this'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

My Array looks something like:

```
tsArr:Array
  0:Array
    0:"2020-09-16T09:18:50.806Z"
    1:"2020-09-16T09:18:50.983Z"
    2:"2020-09-16T09:18:51.164Z"
    3:"2020-09-16T09:18:50.855Z"
    4:"2020-09-16T09:18:51.044Z"
```

I am getting this error in the project stage where I am trying to `$map`:

```
$dateFromString requires that 'dateString' be a string, 
found: array with value ["2020-09-18T00:09:05.569Z", "2020-09-18T00:16:59.297Z",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised my array was nested, so I needed to iterate through the inner array by doing another`$map`. did the trick.

```
{
  _id: 1,
  convertedTsArr: {
    $map: {
      input: '$tsArr',
      in: {
        $map: {
          input: '$$this',
          in: {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: '$$this'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

convertedArray:

```
convertedTsArr:Array
0:Array
0:2020-09-18T00:10:52.542+00:00
1:2020-09-18T00:31:21.980+00:00
2:2020-09-18T00:44:51.123+00:00
3:2020-09-18T00:57:14.435+00:00
4:2020-09-18T01:18:33.845+00:00
```